# How to pass variable from child function to parent function(Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, variables, controller

I want to pass the `$new_token` variable from verified function in app to the verify function in controller. but I dont know how.

My Controller:

```php
public function verify($token)
{
    User::where('email_token',$token)->firstOrFail()->verified();


// I want to bring back variable $new_token from verified function
    $email = new EmailAdmVerification(new User(['email_token' => $new_token, 
    'name' => $user->name]));         
    return redirect('login');
}
```

My App

```php
public function verified()
{
    $new_token = str_random(10);
    $this->email_token = $new_token;
    $this->save();
}
```

Thanks you very much for any help or feedback

Answer (score 0):

Just return it from your function:

```php
public function verified()
{
    $new_token = str_random(10);
    $this->email_token = $new_token;
    $this->save();

    return $new_token; // <----
}
```

Now that this method returns your desired value, you can retrieve it wherever you need it:

```php
 public function verify($token)
{
    $new_token = User::where('email_token',$token)->firstOrFail()->verified(); // <--

    $email = new EmailAdmVerification(new User(['email_token' => $new_token, 
    'name' => $user->name]));    

    return redirect('login');
}
```